# Android - LocalBroadcastManager for SMS interception not firing

Tags: android, localbroadcastmanager

I've got an `JavascriptInterface` method that registers a `LocalBroadcastManager` listening to received SMS's. When an SMS arrives the onReceive method doesn't get called.

```
public void UIregisterSMSSource(String number) {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
        .registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVE));
}

/**
* SMS Receiver
*/
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SMS_RECEIVE)) {
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                    Log.d(TAG, "[SMS] onReceive by " + sender + ". Content - " + body);
                    // Save preferences of the activation code

                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is the ACTION_SMS_RECEIVE variable:

```
private static final String ACTION_SMS_RECEIVE = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
```

I've tested this before as BroadcastaReceiver and it worked. I removed the receiver from the manifest too which I don't know if it's right.

Do I need to configure something more? On the examples I've came across there's no further configuration needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must be sure that the context of the broadcast receiver is  not in a "non-started" state. Android will not fire broadcasts that are stand alone and not somehow referenced by any application or android service.

Comment: @BogdanV. there's a MainActivity that contains all the logic above. The context given to the LocalBroadcastManager it's that Activity. Maybe I wrote it wrong when I stated that I've used a stand alone broadcast before. I meant a simple receiver on a separate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receiver `mMessageReceiver` can only listen the intent which sent via [**`LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent)`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)).

Here, intent with `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action, is being raised by system (not using [**`LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent)`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent))), so your app does not listen to this intent.

Your previous approach was correct, and you can continue on that logic.

---

*You can read a detailed [example of LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html) to make clear your doubts about its working flow.*